# SugarCRM edit lead forms "Edit View" and "Quick Create"

Tags: forms, sugarcrm, custom-fields, lead

I have altered the "edit view" and "quick create" forms for the lead but there is this primary address block that always appear in the middle of the form. How can I remove that ? Please take a look at the snapshot to have a closer look into the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First off, try doing a 'Quick Rebuild and Repair', which should clear out the cached template and rebuild it from scratch.

If that doesn't help, look for a file named 'custom/modules/Leads/editviewdefs.php' and look for the 'primary_address_street' field in there; if found then remove that array entry.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the whole block you need to remove all the fields in both edit and detail view. You have to be sure to remove all fields, if only one of them exist it appear the whole block again.